# Git make error: process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -s 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed. make: config.mak.uname:7: pipe: No error

Tags: git

I am building Git using Clion on Win10. When I ran the "make" command, I met the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -s 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed.
make: config.mak.uname:7: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -m 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed.
make: config.mak.uname:8: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -o 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed.
make: config.mak.uname:9: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -r 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed.
make: config.mak.uname:10: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -p 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed.
make: config.mak.uname:11: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh -c "uname -v 2>/dev/null || echo not", ...) failed.
make: config.mak.uname:12: pipe: No error
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Silly question, but do you _have_ a POSIX-compliant shell? Can't run `sh` if you don't have it installed...